# grunt sass add comment to output file

Tags: wordpress, sass, gruntjs

I'm using grunt sass to output my css in a Wordpress theme.

I would normally output my css to thestyles.css and in the style.css use @import(thestyles.css)

I'm using respond.js so I can't use @import in the style.css file.

I want to output my css straight to the style.css but I need the comments at the top for Wordpress.

```
*/
Theme Name: Forum
Theme URI: 
Description: 
Author:
Author URI: 
Version: 1.0
Tags:
/*
```

Can I use banner to add the comments

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      banner:
      '
      */
      Theme Name: Forum
      Theme URI: 
      Description: 
      Author:
      Author URI: 
      Version: 1.0
      Tags:
      /*
      '
    },
    files: {
      "src/php/wp-content/themes/forum/style.css": "src/sass/forum/output.scss"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: [Sure.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#banner)

Answer (score 5):

You should put a ! so the banner is not removed by a minifier.

You can pull your info from the package.json also like this:

In Gruntfile.js

```
pkg: pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*!\n' +
              ' * Theme Name: Forum\n' +
              ' * Theme URI: <%= pkg.url %>\n' +
              ' * Description: <%= pkg.description %>\n' +
              ' * Author: <%= pkg.author.name %>\n' +
              ' * Author URI: <%= pkg.author.email %>\n' +
              ' * Version: <%= pkg.version %>\n' +
              ' * Tags:\n' +
              ' */\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly in v0.9.0 (realsed in February 2015) baner option has been removed from grunt-contrib-sass. I used this task [grunt-banner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-banner) and it works just fine.